# Update Apache rewrite rule in .htacess that will still allow for previous URLs to work

Tags: .htaccess

I'm working on updating an .htaccess file to update some URLs for an existing website.
Right now, the URLs look like:

nickwebsite.com/**nicks-widgets**/product-type

I'm trying to reduce the redundancy, to have the URLs look like:

nickwebsite.com/**widgets**/product-type

The RewriteRules in place now look like this:
`RewriteRule ^nicks-widgets/product-type(.*)$ collection.php?category_id=64&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC]`

I need to update these URLs to use the new URL, while still keeping the old URLS functional

I tried adding a Rewrite rule like so:
`RewriteRule ^widgets/product-type(.*)$ collection.php?category_id=64&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC]`

And also a Redirect like this, so that visitors who have the old URL saved will be redirected to the new URL:
`Redirect 301 /nicks-widgets /widgets`

But neither really work. Instead I'm seeing my URL combined when trying to access the new url, so I will get:nickwebsite.com/widgetsproduct-type?category_id=64 displayed in my browser. I'm really lost on what I am missing.. can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts in your question. Could you please do add more clear details on: FROM which url TO which urls you need to redirect/rewrite? That will give us better picture of your question, thank you.

Comment: Also, show your full rewrite configuration please, so that we can see what you tried in context. Only then will we be able to tell if other rules might be interfering.